# Loop in list and sublist of JToken JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file and list with sublist like this :

```
ListCmsControl 
|
|----ControlList
|        Name
|          |----ControlList
|                 Name
|          |----ControlList
|                 Name   
|
|----ControlList
|          |----ControlList
|          |----ControlList
|
|----ControlList
|          |----ControlList
|                   Name   
|          |----ControlList
|                   Name
```

And CmsControls CLASS :

```
public class CmsControls
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CmsControls> ControlList { get; set; }
}
```

I want to loop within this list and get the name of each list control

I tried this code :

```
public List<CmsControls> GetCmsControls()
{
    List<CmsControls> controls = new List<CmsControls>();

    foreach (var CmsControls in BaseToken.SelectToken("ListCmsControl"))
    {

        cmsControls(CmsControls, ref controls);
    }

    return controls;
}

private void cmsControls(JToken controls, ref List<CmsControls> ctrl)
{
    foreach (var control in controls)
    {
        var jtoken = control.SelectToken("ControlList");
        ctrl.Add(jtoken.ToObject<CmsControls>());
        cmsControls(jtoken, ref ctrl);
    }
}
```

But i get only the first level.

Comment: What does boucle mean? Google couldn't help.

Comment: Loop... boucle is in french... ;)